# rails params hash to String:String hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am doing an http get using the url `http://localhost/add?add_key[0][key]=1234&add_key[0][id]=1.` 
I have a rails app which gives me a neat params hash {"add_key"=>{"0"=>{"key"=>"1234", "id"=>"1"}}. However when I try to post this to a different server using

```
new_uri = URI.parse("http://10.10.12.1/test") 
res = Net::HTTP.post_form new_uri,params
```

The server handling the post is seeing this parameter in the request

```
{"add_key"=>"0key1234id1"}
```

Looks like post_form requires a String to String hash. So how do I convert the params hash to

```
{"add_key[0][key]" => "1234", add_key[0][id]" => "1"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form):

> **post_form(url, params)**
>   Posts HTML form data to the specified URI object. The form data must be provided as a Hash mapping from String to String.

So you're right about what `params` needs to be.

You could grab the parsed `params` in your controller:

```
{"add_key"=>{"0"=>{"key"=>"1234", "id"=>"1"}}
```

and then recursively pack that back to the flattened format that `post_form` expects but that would be a lot of pointless busy work. An easy way to do this would be to grab the raw URL and parse it yourself with [`URI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) and [`CGI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse), something like this in your controller:

```
u = URI.parse(request.url)
p = CGI.parse(u.query)
```

That will leave you with `{"add_key[0][key]" => "1234", "add_key[0][id]" => "1"}` in `p` and then you can hand that `p` to `Net::HTTP.post_form`.

Comment: That worked great!! Is there any rails way of redirecting the request to another server?

Comment: @Vasu: Nothing comes to mind but I've never had a need for it. I don't know if redirecting to a POST is going to work that well.

Comment: If the original request was a POST, do CGI.parse(request.raw_post)